# How to make a class member function edit the value of global variable

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

```
int var1 = 0;
int var2 = 10;

class cls{

    int varA;
    int *varB;

public:
    cls(int valueA, int *valueB){
        varA = valueA;
        *varB = *valueB;
    }

    void putValueAtoVar2(void){
        *varB = varA;
    }
}

void setup(){
    cls cls1(var1, &var2);
}

void loop(){
    cls1.putValueAtoVar2();
}
```

I'm confused here, I am trying to make a function of a class to change a variable in the global area.

If I wrote the code like above, would it be correct?

If not please can someone teach me how, or is there a better way to do it?

My goal is to create an instance of `cls` named `cls1`, `cls1.varA = var1` which is `0` and when function `putvalueAtoVar2` is ran, it should change the global variable `var2`, which is `10` to the value of `cls1.varA` which is `0`.

Comment: You are not initializing `varB` to point to a valid (properly allocated) block of memory.

Comment: I am with @goodvibration Did you maybe not show relevant code? Please provide a [mre].

Comment: @ZhuSong I improved your edit, in the future, when editing a post please be sure to give it a global overview, though your change is accurate, you left other problems behind.

Comment: instead of `*varB = *valueB;` i think you want `varB = valueB;`

Comment: @goodvibration didn't I initialize it as a pointer of an integer?

Comment: @anastaciu thankyou, will improve my way of posting next time.

Comment: Since `varB` in not pointing to a valid (properly allocated) block of memory, you cannot use `*varB` in order to access (read or right) memory.

Comment: @user2419340, my message was to ZhuSong, but I'm glad you took something from it, cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this

before global variable are `globalVar1=0` and `globalVar2=10` after

assigning instance variable cls.varA to globalVar2, becomes  `globalVar2=0`

Below is the following code :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int globalVar1 = 0;
int globalVar2 = 10;

class cls{

    int varA;
    int *varB;

public:
    cls(int gVar1,int* gVar2){
        varA = gVar1;
        varB = gVar2;
    }

    void putValueAtoVar2(void){
        *varB = varA;
    }
};


int main()
{
    //setup
    cls cls1(globalVar1, &globalVar2);
    cout<<"global variable "<<"1st : "<<globalVar1<<" 2nd : "<<globalVar2<<endl;
    //changing the value of global variable
    cls1.putValueAtoVar2();
    cout<<"After changing global variable "<<endl;
    cout<<"global variable "<<"1st : "<<globalVar1<<" 2nd : "<<globalVar2<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ah so my big mistake was only on the class constructor, i should not add the * symbol? edit : i wrote *varB = *valueB, while i should wrote varB=valueB?

Comment: Yes you just have to change that